# Is this a bug in the TextBlob library in Python when parsing contractions like 'gonna'?

Tags: python, textblob

I am trying to use TextBlob library for information extraction from text. I stumbled upon this error which caused me a lot of problem. Kindly tell me why this is happening and Is there any way to avoid it or I will have to ignore such words in the text and move on.

```
> from textblob import TextBlob as tb
> temp = tb('gonna')
> print(temp.words)
['gon', 'na']
```

The same issue occurs with words like "wanna", "let's" etc.